# I need a KQL query returning top X records each grouping

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Assume a table called Cities like the following:

```
GA   Augusta       203953
GA   Athens        130873
GA   Atlanta       522328
GA   Savannah      151227
FL   Orlando       328354
FL   Tampa         399734
FL   Miami         455075
FL   Jacksonville  987960
```

I need a KQL query returning the top 2 cities ranked by population for each state.
For example, here is the expected result:

```
FL   Jacksonville  987960
FL   Miami         455075
GA   Atlanta       522328
GA   Augusta       203953
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [`partition` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/partitionoperator)

for example:

```
datatable(state:string, city:string, population:long)
[
    "GA", "Augusta", 203953,
    "GA", "Athens", 130873,
    "GA", "Atlanta", 522328,
    "GA", "Savannah", 151227,
    "FL", "Orlando", 328354,
    "FL", "Tampa", 399734,
    "FL", "Miami", 455075,
    "FL", "Jacksonville", 987960,
]
| partition by state ( top 2 by population desc )
```

| state | city | population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GA | Atlanta | 522328 |
| GA | Augusta | 203953 |
| FL | Jacksonville | 987960 |
| FL | Miami | 455075 |

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I needed, and it's a lot more understandable than the plate of spaghetti code that ChatGPT suggested.